# Meteor package incorrect folder name

Tags: meteor, package

I just ran the following meteor command:

sudo meteor create --package blah:my-package

and meteor has created a folder called TECM60~2 ... I thought it was supposed to create a folder with the package name - any ideas?

Note: I am running Ubuntu on Virtualbox (developing on Windows) and accessing the package folder via a Samba share to Windows Explorer. I suspect this problem is because Windows does not allow colons in folder names (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Ethaan's comment, it is possible to create packages without the username: in front of it. I did raise this with the Meteor team and they said they will address this in a fuuture release.